# Data structure for nested storage map

Tags: substrate, polkadot

How to declare the type for following data structure?

A product can have many candidates and each candidate has a stake. But same candidate can remain in more than one product with different stakes. I also need to query stake from a candidate id, and candidate ids from product id.

```
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn governor_group)]
    pub type ProductId<T> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, ProductId, Vec<CandidateId>>; 

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn candidate_nominee)]
    pub type Stakes<T> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, CandidateId, Stake>;
```

In the above code each candidate can have only one stake.

Nested storage map are not allowed in substrate like:

```
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn governor_group)]
    pub type ProductId<T> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, ProductId, Stakes>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [`StorageDoubleMap`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html).

This allows you to have:

```
Key -> Key -> Value
```

So that would look like:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn governor_group)]
pub type ProductId<T> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    ProductId,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    CandidateId,
    Stakes,
>;
```

You may need to introduce other maps which clarify sub-context of this double map, or create some data structures which hold the information you are looking for.

Note that we support an arbitrary nesting of maps with [`StorageNMap`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageNMap.html), which just extends this concept further and further.

Comment: But I want the number (length) of candidateids (key2) for the productid (key1), how can I get that? Any function?

Comment: Also I will be needing two keys to fetch the value, how to fetch all the candidateIds and stakes for a productId?

Comment: Got it, there is a function called iter_key_prefix. Thanks. https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html#method.iter_key_prefix

Comment: Your first question, you will need to keep track of the length of the map in a separate storage value.

It is not a good idea to fetch everything at once in the runtime, it will be a very expensive storage read operation, and can be very bad for your chain. If you need all the data you should be using a vec with limited size.

If this answered your question, please mark it as answered.